# How to configure protected access to files on remote nginx with X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have 2 servers. First (domain.com) is a django/apache server, second (f1.domain.com) is a file server (nginx). Some files are protected and should only be allowed to be downloaded by registred users. To that end I have setup a nginx server with a

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name *.domain.com;
        access_log /home/domain/logs/access.log;
        location /files/ {
             internal;
             root /home/domain;
        }
}
```

and from Django I send a request via X-Accel-Redirect header, but it doesn't work. I think because the request comes from a remote server.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: I am confused a bit by your question.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"and from django I send a request via X-Accel-Redirect header"  -- it's incorrect, the "X-Accel" header must be a part of response header from the upstream server.

As http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel said, there must be a proxy_pass or fastcgi_pass directive to send the response header to nginx.

```
location /protected_files { 
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.2; 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could be more clear about the fact that there should be a nginx reverse proxy in front of the Apache/Django server and the nginx file server (or have the reverse proxy act as the fileserver too). A bit like [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/491/).